# Generating annual estimates of N of a binomial distribution

Tags: r, jags

I'm trying to estimate N from a binomial distribution as in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113851/bayesian-estimation-of-n-of-a-binomial-distribution. I have 40 years of counts and an estimated success rate. I'd like to generate an estimate of N for each year. I'm new to JAGS and thought I could get estimates of N by adding an index (n[i]), but I get the following error: "Index out of range taking subset of n." Am I completely off base in what I'm trying to do here? Below is a model and random dataset that I thought would generate annual estimates of N. I do have a model working that generates a single estimate of N, which is just removing the index ([i]) from n in the likelihood (dbin(theta, n)). Thanks in advance for your help.

```
sink("file.jags")
cat("
    model {

    ## Likelihood    
    for (i in 1:nyear) {
      
      x[i] ~ dbin(theta, n[i])
     
    }

    ## Priors    
    lambda ~ dgamma(0.005, 0.005)    
    theta ~ dbeta(22, 37)
    mu <- lambda/theta
    n ~ dpois(mu)
    
}    
", fill = TRUE)

sink()

# Initial values
inits <- function() { 
  list(
    n = sample(1:100
               , size = 1) 
    , lambda = runif(1, 1, 100)
  )
}

# Parameters monitored
params <- c('theta'
            , 'n'
)

# MCMC settings
ni <- 2000
nb <- 200
nc <- 3

# Bundle data
jags.data <- list(n = c(round(runif(40, 1, 100)))
                  , nyear = 40)

# Fit model
out <- jagsUI(data = jags.data
              , inits = inits
              , parameters.to.save = params
              , model.file = "file.jags"
              , n.chains = nc
              , n.iter = ni
              , n.burnin = nb
              , verbose = TRUE)

# Summarize posteriors
print(out$summary, dig = 2)
```

EDIT 1: As suggested by @DaveArmstrong, I needed to include the prior for n in the for loop to generate annual priors. Additionally, I removed n from the initial values list because I was receiving a dimension mismatch error in 'setParameters'. Once I removed n from the 'inits' the model ran.

I also switched the prior on lambda from a gamma to a uniform based on my interpretation of Dave's point re: the model not being able to initialize. After I got the model running, I checked to see if the different prior on lambda had an effect and it didn't. The model still ran using the 'dgamma(0.005, 0.005)' but I'm leaving the dunif prior in.

```
"model {

    # Likelihood    
    for (i in 1:nyear) {
      
      reported_morts[i] ~ dbin(report_rate, total_morts[i])
      
      # Annual prior for total mortality. Necessary to get annual estimates.
      total_morts[i] ~ dpois(mu)
    }

    # Priors
    lambda ~ dunif(1, 100)
    report_rate ~ dbeta(22, 37)
    mu <- round(lambda/report_rate)
    
}"  

# Initial values. Removed "n = sample(1:100, size = 1)".
inits <- function() { 
  list(
    lambda = runif(1, 1, 100)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it by changing the model to something like this:

```r
mod <- "model {

    ## Likelihood    
    for (i in 1:nyear) {
      
      x[i] ~ dbin(theta, n[i])
      n[i] ~ dpois(mu)
     
    }

    ## Priors    
    lambda ~ dgamma(0.005, 0.005)    
    theta ~ dbeta(22, 37)
    mu <- lambda/theta
}    
"
```

The problem before was that `n` was a scalar in the prior, but a vector in the model.  You've got to put a prior on each value of `n`.  That model is syntactically correct, but it doesn't initialize because the priors you've set are very far away from the data.  If you just get the prior predictive distribution of `x`, their posterior means are all less than 0.1, but the data for `x` is integer values between 1 and 100.  This generates a 'node inconsistent with parent' error.  I assume these are just dummy data, so perhaps your real problem will work alright.  Otherwise, the priors will have to be a bit more realistic to work.

Comment: In previous iterations, I did put the prior for 'n' in the for loop but I kept receiving an dimension mismatch error. Now, I see it was likely my initial values. I was only supplying a single value when I'm guessing I needed to supply one for each year. Thanks for your help, Dave. Much appreciated.